# excel vba variables in functions

Tags: excel, vba

i have an automation that performs a few different actions which definitely requires a login, so i coded all the actions in modules and have 1 main login script that will call upon the different modules base on the codes that was sent by the buttons.

Buttons

```
Sub Button_Click()
    Call LoginPhase(F1Function1)
DoEvents
End Sub
```

Function

```
Public Function LoginPhase(FunctionKey)

....

        If FunctionKey = "F1Function1" Then
            Call Scrape(intX)
        ElseIf FunctionKey = "F2Function2" Then
            Call BuyBuyBuy(intX, Epin)
            Call Scrape(intX)
        ElseIf FunctionKey = "F3Function3" Then
            Call BuyBuyBuy2(intX, Epin)
            Call Scrape(intX)
        Else
            MsgBox "Not Relevant."
        End If

....

End Function
```

But it seem that it never recognize any of the FunctionKey value and goes straight to MsgBox "Not Relevant". Anyone have any idea how i can solve this ?

Comment: Did you pass anything? What's stored in `F1Function1`? Edit: or did you mean to pass it as a string?

Comment: meant to pass it as a string in the LoginPhase(F1Function1) i guess? So that i can differentiate F1Function1 and F2Function2 when i'm in the LoginPhase function

Comment: As is currently written, you're passing in a *variable* named `F1Function`. If you mean to pass it as a *string*, you should be using `Call LoginPhase("F1Function1")` (note that F1Function1 is surrounded in quotes)

Comment: Ah damn, thanks for the tip, kept forgetting about that.

Comment: If you add `Option Explicit` to the top of your modules then the compiler will catch those kind of errors. If you select Tools > Options > Editor > Require variable declaration then Option Explicit will be automatically added to new modules